# Blazor gives http error 500 when passing ClaimsPrincipal but I can not catch any error in the controller block

Tags: authentication, blazor, authorization

here is the code:

```
[HttpPost("CreateUser")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<RegisterResponseModel>> CreateUser(RegisterModel registreModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return new RegisterResponseModel { Success = false, Message = "model not valid" };
            }
            var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = registreModel.Email, Email = registreModel.Email };
            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, registreModel.Password);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                string errors = string.Empty;
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    errors = $"{errors} , {error.Code} ";
                }
                return new RegisterResponseModel { Success = false, Message = errors };
            }
            await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

            ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            RegisterResponseModel response = new RegisterResponseModel { Success = true, Message = user.Email, Principal = principal };
            return response;
        }
```

I did tried to use try catch block but it did not catch any error, I also debug step by step and the program goes throw all lines without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

blazor is designed to not send ClaimsPrincipal because it contains sensitive data and here is the code that work

```
[HttpPost("CreateUser")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<RegisterResponseModel>> CreateUser(RegisterModel registreModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return new RegisterResponseModel { Success = false, Message = "model not valid" };
        }
        var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = registreModel.Email, Email = registreModel.Email };
        var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, registreModel.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            string errors = string.Empty;
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                errors = $"{errors} , {error.Code} ";
            }
            return new RegisterResponseModel { Success = false, Message = errors };
        }
        await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);


        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
        List<UserClaim> userClaims = new List<UserClaim> { new UserClaim { Type =ClaimTypes.Name, Name = user.UserName } };
        foreach (var item in userClaims)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.Type} {item.Name}");
        }
        RegisterResponseModel response = new RegisterResponseModel { Success = true, Message = user.Email, Claims = userClaims };
        return response;
    }
```